# jQuery contents from a higher level?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery that mostly works:

```
$("article > p, article > div, article > ol > li, article > ul > li").contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) {
        strippedValue = $.trim($(this).text());
        doStuff(strippedValue);
    }

    if (this.nodeType === 1) {
        strippedValue = $.trim($(this).html());
        doStuff(strippedValue);
    }
})
```

The problems comes when (inside `doStuff()`) I try to replace HTML tags. Here is a view of my elements:

[image]

And I'm trying to replace those `<kbd>` tags thusly:

```
newStr = newStr.replace(/<kbd>/g, " <b>");  
newStr = newStr.replace(/<\/kbd>/g, "<b> ");
```

That doesn't work, and I'm seeing in the debugger that the `<kbd>` tags are seen as first-class children and looped separately. Whereas I want everything inside my selectors to be seen as a raw string so I can replace things. And I realize I'm asking for a contradiction, because `.contents()` means get children and their contents. So if I have a selector that is a direct parent of `<kbd>`, then `<kdb>` ceases to become a raw string and becomes instead a node that is being looped.

So it seems like my selectors are wrong BUT whenever I try to bring my selectors higher in the hierarchy, immediately I lose textual contents and I end up with a bunch of html with no contents inside the elements. (The screenshot shows good contents, as expected.)

So for example I tried this:

```
$("article").contents().each(function() {
   ...
}
```

...hoping that the selector looping would occur a little higher, and thus allow HTML tags further down to come through as raw text. But clearly I'm lost.

My objective is to simply perform a bunch of string replacements on the contents of the html. But there are two challenges with this:

1. The page contents load dynamically, with ajaxy calls or similar, so full contents are not available until about a second or two after page load.
2. When I try to grab high-level elements such as `body`, it ends up devoid of much of the textual contents. The selectors I currently have don't suffer from that problem; those get everything I want BUT then HTML/XML elements get looped instead of coming through as plain text so that I can perform replacements.

Comment: What about `$(this).prop('outerHTML')` or `$(this).html()`(inner)?

Comment: `$(this).html()` is already happening inside the loop.

Comment: So basically you want to change `kbd` tag to something else and that is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to perform the modification on raw HTML? You could just replace the DOM elements directly (not to mention that this is much more reliable then using string replacement):

```js
$('kbd').replaceWith(function() {
  return ` <b>${this.textContent}</b> `;
  // or directly create DOM elements:
  // const b = document.createElement('b');
  // b.textContent = this.textContent;
  // return b;
});
console.log($('b').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<kbd>hello world</kbd>
```

Of course you can still do string replacements where it makes sense, but you should work with DOM elements as much as possible.

Comment: Felix, your approach led me to the solution I was looking for, which is this: `$('kbd').replaceWith(function() { return " <b>" + this.textContent + "</b> " });` - notice there are spaces at the beginning and end. if you can modify your answer accordingly I'll award you the answer and the bounty. I just needed a bit more flexibility, so replacing with arbitrary html is really what I needed.

Comment: Of course you can do that too, yes :)

Comment: Thanks Felix. This was exactly what I needed.